# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client. Cannot find where the other response is being sent. Maybe componentDidMount method

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose

I have gone through many responses on this topic but none seem to solve my issue. I have an API using NodeJS, ExpressJS and Mongoose. I also have a frontend component that is built using ReactJS. I get the above error on the second or more try when saving data from a form. **Note: the error does not show up on the first attempt at saving the form.**
The backend code for saving the request to the database is

```
candidate.save()
    .then(result => {
      res.status(200).send({
        candidate: result,
        message: result.name + " has been added successfully"
      });
    }).catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({ message: err.message || "An error occurred while creating the candidate" });
    });
```

The code that takes the data from the form and makes the request is

```
CandidateDataService.create(candidate).then(response => {
      this.setState({
        name: response.data.name,
        dob: response.data.dob,
        gender: response.data.gender,
        party: response.data.party,
        district: response.data.district,
        comments: response.data.comments,

        submitted: response.data.message
      });
    }).catch(e => { console.log(e) });
```

The create method in CandidateDataService is

```
create(candidate) {
    return http.post("/candidates", candidate);
  }
```

**I have tried using** `return res.status(200)` as stated in answers to similar questions but that didn't work.

I should mention that I have similar code in other controllers for forms that store data and I don't get this error on the NodeJS side. So I don't understand why it works for the others with the exact same code style but not this one. On the ReactJS side there is a difference though. The difference is that this component has the ComponentDidMount method and the others don't. In the ComponentDidMount method I'm fetching all the data from two separate Models to fill the select list.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.retrieveDistricts();
  this.retrieveParties();
}
```

```
retrieveDistricts() {
    DistrictDataService.getAll()
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          districts: response.data
        });
      }).catch(e => { console.log(e) });
  }
```

```
retrieveParties() {
    PartyDataService.getAll()
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          parties: response.data
        });
      }).catch(e => { console.log(e) });
  }
```

I tried it this way in the componentDidMount method but still the same result

```
componentDidMount() {
    PartyDataService.getAll()
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({parties: response.data});
        DistrictDataService.getAll()
          .then(districts => {
            this.setState({districts: districts.data});
          });
      }).catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
```

Since this is the only thing different between this form and the others I believe that's what causing the error, but I don't understand why or how to fix it.

**Summary**

1. No issues when using postman to create entries.
2. The error does not appear the first time the form is save via the frontend. In rare occassions it did not appear on the second attempt either but it always appear on the third attempt.
3. BackEnd and FrontEnd code works perfect for other forms, that does not need to be prefilled.
4. Can it be the methods inside componentDidMount? If so, why?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After trying multiple tweaks based on hints I received on similar post nothing worked. Playing with the react plugin for firefox, I noticed that the state of the inputs would change to undefined. I realize that there was an error in the variable I used to pass the data to the react state. So this caused the undefined I was getting.
Then in the console tab I noticed an error that said something with respect to uncontrolled and controlled inputs. Apparently my inputs were controlled but then became uncontrolled when I passed the response data to the set the state. This was not necessary.

After I stopped passing the response data to set the state, the error described above stopped appearing. I don't understand why or the theory behind it, but it did the trick.

Hopefully this helps someone else.